# Getting content after string interpolation in Angular2 Directive

Tags: angular

Using Angular2.x

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<p myCustomDirective>{{someVar}}</p>
```

How can I access the rendered/interpolated value for {{someVar}} from within one of the directive lifecycle hooks? I want to be able to reference and use the value of 'someVar' in my directive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easist way of doing this might be injecting `ElementRef` into directive and read [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) value from its `nativeElement` property:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myCustomDirective]'
})
export class MyCustomDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.textContent);
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6NYUcGZ2h6fT2VsLg82n?p=preview)**

Comment: Perfect! the ngAfterViewInit + textContent seems to be the magic sauce I wasn't finding.